# Managing states in nested components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following structure, where in my `headButtons` component I am trying to receive a prop to change a state in my `ProfileDetail`

- TitleContainer

  - headButtons.js
  - TitleContainer.js
- Profile Detail

  - ProfileDetail.js

**HeadButtons.js**

```
const HeadButtons = ({ action }) => {
  return (
    <Buttons>
      <li>
        <Link to="#">Export</Link>
      </li>
      <li className="active">
        <Link to="#" onClick={action}>Add</Link>
      </li>
    </Buttons>
  )}
```

and I am importing this component inside my `TitleContainer`

```
import HeadButtons from './HeadButtons'
const TitleContainer = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <PageTitle>
        { title }
      </PageTitle>
      <HeadButtons />
     </Container>
  )
}
```

and in my `UserProfileDetail` Im importing both components.

```
export class UserProfileDetail extends Component {

state = {
  ShowModal: false
}

openModal = () => {
  this.setState({
    ShowModal: !ShowModal
  })
}


<TitleContainer title={ userName } action={this.openModal} />
```

What I am not understanding is why my component TitleContainer cant execute the `openModal` to change the state of `ShowModal`.

Any directions ?

Comment: I think you missed to bind the method like `action={this.openModal.bind(this)}`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I should have been forgetting something else, because it didnt worked.

Comment: You have to receive action in `TitleContainer` and pass it to `HeadButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering `HeadButton` component in `TitleContainer`, you aren't passing down the action as prop to it.

```
import HeadButtons from './HeadButtons'
const TitleContainer = ({ title, action }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <PageTitle>
        { title }
      </PageTitle>
      <HeadButtons action={action}/>
     </Container>
  )
}
```